# MYSQL datetime to mongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, datetime

I have converted a MYSQL DB to MongoDB.

One field, publish_datetime was a MYSQL datetime field.

In mongo, I need todo ordering by that datetime field.

Is this possible without converting it to a seperate field as a timestamp?

Comment: What is the type of the field in MongoDB? What what do you mean by timestamp? The data type Timestamp or an integer timestamp?

Comment: the field is a string. There is no timestamp string but I could add a timestamp version of the datetime field if sorting by datetime isnt possible

Comment: Hmm Is the string a formed one like `02/03/2013`? If so then the default string sort could (will) cause a problem. I recommend you use the `ISODate` object that comes with MongoDB and sort on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not really matter which type it is, sorting either a DateTime value or an integer value happens with:

```
db.collection.find().sort( { field_name: 1 } );
```

However, it would be helpful if you showed a sample document that has the "datetime" value in there.